# Photoshop CS5 - making text have effect but with a transparent fill....totally stuck

Tags: text, photoshop, transparent, flash-cs5

I have been using Photoshop for about three weeks now, finding it very different to fireworks...

Im trying to make a cool effect on my site, I want to use JQuery to slide a background image behind some text, and the background show through the text. I need to text to be placed in a white box, with the text itself "punched" out, so you can literally see through it (but only the text, the white box will cover everything else). The text also needs an inner shadow effect...just no fill. I am having real problems finding this info, can anyone help?

Many thanks, Dan

Comment: Just incase anyone is interested. This was a tut I found: http://www.sketchpad.net/cleartext1.htm and Sam's answer solved it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create your white background layer
2. Create your text layer with the font and size you want
3. Ctrl+Click the text icon in the Layers panel to select the outline of your text
4. Select your white background layer and press delete to cut the text shape from your background
5. Select your text layer and delete it
6. Apply your drop shadow or glow filters to your background layer
7. Save as a transparent PNG-24

Comment: Im just going to try yours too, it looks less complicated : )

Comment: Step 4 isn't happening for me. I have the text outline highlighted like you say, and a layer below that's white. Am I supposed to just click the white layer and hit backspace? Nothing is happening..

Comment: Select the background layer in the layers panel so it is the active layer. Your text selection should remain highlighted. When you press delete it will cut the selection from your background. Then select the text layer and delete that layer.

Comment: Score! Looks like I have it, thanks a bunch. Easy when you know what you are doing....

Comment: Remember to have your layer Rasterized in order to do the cutting.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't sound too clear but i think animating the opacity of either of text or background would help.[check this](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: Hi, it's quite tricky to explain. I will be using animate, but not like you think...check this out. http://tinyurl.com/6eeo8v - See how the headings are actually see-through?

Comment: do you mean the texts above the the banner image? I checked out that it is just an image not a text with one of its parent div has  css background as transparent.

Comment: No, the effect is quite subtle, watch the headings down the page, the background shows through...

Comment: if you are not talking about the navigations rest of the headings in that site are image. and the same thing applies the parent div with id header has background as transparent. You do not need any jquery to do this.

Comment: @Dan: But you have not made it clear whether you need help on photoshop or css/jquery.Please elaborate

Comment: At the moment it's the making of the image i'm having issues with. When its done I will absolute position it over another div. The div under it will have the background image (gradient) that will move, I will then see the change in gradient through the text layer on top.